# Is there any way to undo a suspension?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Is there any way to undo a suspension?  Or is a suspension a suspension? Maybe some supermod could be formed like Captain Planet?

Comment: The last sentence seemed irrelevant to your question, so I removed it.  The second two "questions" could be replaced by an elaboration of what you would like to know about how suspensions work, to make your question clearer.

Comment: I support having all mods being able to form together into Captain Plnanet.  Remember that one guy whose power was heart.  That was so weak compared to water and fire and all that.

Answer (score 13):

A diamond moderator can reduce the length of a suspension or lift it outright at their discretion.

This usually happens when the suspended user and the moderator team come to some sort of an understanding or an agreement. Appeals from other people don't (or generally shouldn't) carry much weight because the suspension is a private matter between the moderators and the suspended user.

When a user is suspended, they are sent a mandatory message from the moderators and they can respond to it to discuss or appeal the whole thing.

Comment: The Captain Planet question got me wondering: Are there any moderator abilities for which approval by several community moderators is mandatory?

Comment: @JonasMeyer No, although we strongly encourage moderators to work as a team and discuss unusual or controversial actions. Most actions are reversible (the most common things that aren't are user and comment deletion), so if one moderator takes a misstep, another can easily correct it.